# Does the basin of attraction of an asymptotically stable steady state always have strictly positive Lebesgue measure?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, epsilon-delta, stability-theory

Consider the $n$-dimensional [autonomous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) $\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{y}(t)=f(\boldsymbol{y}(t))$ defined on $[a,b]^n$, where $\mbox{-}\infty<a<b<\infty$.$^1$

Suppose that $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ is an [asymptotically stable steady state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Definition_for_continuous-time_systems).$^2$ Does it then follow that its *basin of attraction*

$$\left\{\boldsymbol{y}(0)\in[a,b]^n: \lim_{t\to\infty} \boldsymbol{y}(t)= \tilde{\boldsymbol{y}} \right\}$$
has strictly positive [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure)?

---

**Footnotes:**

1. By this I mean that $f:[a,b]^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined in a way such that $\{\boldsymbol{y}(t):t\geq 0\}\subseteq [a,b]^n$ whenever $\boldsymbol{y}(0)\in[a,b]^n$. (And initial conditions not in $[a,b]^n$ are excluded from analysis).
2. In the present context, $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ is an  *asymptotically stable steady state* if both of the following hold:

   1. $f(\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}) = 0$
   2. $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. if $\boldsymbol{y}(0)\in[a,b]^n$ and $||\boldsymbol{y}(0)-\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}||_2<\delta$, then $||\boldsymbol{y}(t)-\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}||_2<\varepsilon$ $\forall t\geq 0$ and $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} || ||\boldsymbol{y}(t)-\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}||_2 = 0$, where $|| \cdot ||_2$ denotes the [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm).

Comment: So does $B(\tilde{\bf y},δ)$ have a positive measure?

Comment: Hi @LutzLehmann, thanks so much for taking the time to respond to my question!

By $B(\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}},\delta)$, do you mean $$\left\{\boldsymbol{y}(0)\in[a,b]^n \cap N_\delta(\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}) : \lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \boldsymbol{y}(t) = \tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}\right\},$$ where $N_\delta(\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}})$ denotes the $\delta$-ball centered at $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$?

Comment: No, I mean what you write as $N_δ({\bf\tilde y})$, the convergence is implied from the absolute stability, or its part in the box. Do you consider equilibria at the boundary for the general statement?

Comment: I see. So to answer your first question: yes, the $\delta$-ball of $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ has positive measure (given $\delta>0$, of course).

For your second question: if you mean "do I allow $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ on the boundary $\partial\left([a,b]^n\right)$?" the answer is yes. (Does that make a difference? )

Comment: Yes. Arguing about the slices could be tedious, but in the end even the spherical section at a corner will have a positive measure.

Comment: I see! I think the answer to my question is now immediate, but may I please double check that we are on the same page?

If $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ is an asymptotically stable steady state, it follows that $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. all $\boldsymbol{y}(0)$ in a $\delta$-ball of $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ (intersected with $[a,b]^n$) yield trajectories that asymptote towards $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$. Said set has positive measure, and is a subset of $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$'s basin of attraction, and therefore the latter set has positive measure.

Comment: (Of course, the above is just a sketch of a proof. Moreover, as you mentioned, extra care must be taken for $\tilde{\boldsymbol{y}}$ on the boundary of $[a,b]^n$.)

In any case, I just wanted to thank you again for your help Professor Lehmann!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138897/discussion-between-cluelessmathematician-and-lutz-lehmann).